# Remove partition from devices

Tags: 11.10, partitioning

I want to remove my windows and recovery partition from under the devices so that no one accidentally edits them. I'm using ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: what do you mean by _from under the devices_?

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking by devices you mean under `/dev` like `/dev/sdaX` ,`/dev/sdaY` and so on. That I am afraid is not possible. You could follow *bkzland's* instructions and stop your those two NTFS drives (Windows partition & Recovery Partition) from auto-mounting on startup, if they do.

Another viable option using the *fstab* file is to limit the permissions of who can access/edit the two partitions. You could take a look at the [Ubuntu Community Documentation on fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) to achieve any of these solutions.

Just to prevent other users from touching those partitions from the Nautilus side-bar, you could follow the instructions on [this page](http://www.worldofnubcraft.com/969/hide-your-disks-or-partitions-from-nautilus/) and also [this thread at UbuntuForums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1496408) to do that. I haven't tested either of them myself personally, but just saying that you could. But even then, your drives will show up in command-line tools like `fdisk`, `blkid` and such and also on disk-utility programs like *Gparted partition editor* and such.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to edit your `/etc/fstab` file and exclude the automatically configured NTFS devices for your windows partitions. Just take a look in there and comment out the lines referencing any NTFS or windows partition. You will need to be root to edit this file using `sudo su -`. These settings will take effect after a reboot, you can also unmount them manually with `umount` and skip the reboot.